# How to apply `abs2` to a `CuArray{Complex{Int8}}` while avoiding overflow

Tags: julia, gpu, gpgpu

This question appeared on the julialang Slack helpdesk channel

---

How do I calculate the `abs2` of a `Complex{Int8}` array without the elements exceeding the max value of `Int8` and without increasing CPU->GPU transfer time? I have two pre-allocated `CuArray`s of eltype `Complex{Int8}` and `Int32`. The result of `abs2` of the complex array should be stored in the `Int32` `CuArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is essentially the same as if it were on the CPU thanks to julia's generic interfaces.

```
using CUDA

let v = CUDA.rand(Complex{Int8}, 10)
    u = CUDA.zeros(Int32, length(v))
    u .= abs2.(Complex{Int32}.(v))
end
```

```
10-element CuArray{Int32,1}:
   424
 16201
 18253
  1305
 19109
 13322
  8948
 18401
  8840
   628
```

In this snippet, I used [broadcasting](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting) to convert each element of `u` to `Complex{Int32}` and then applied `abs2` to that and stored the result in `u`. Thanks to the broadcast semantics, all of the loops above were fused so no temporaries were created.

Alerernatively, this can be achieved with an inplace map,

```
let v = CUDA.rand(Complex{Int8}, 10)
    u = CUDA.zeros(Int32, length(v))
    map!(x -> abs2(Complex{Int32}(x)), u, v)
end
```

```
10-element CuArray{Int32,1}:
 12682
  5821
 12676
 19061
  6025
   433
  8609
   205
  2125
 11169
```